# Leverage Trading with Phemex API via ccxt

Tags: python, api, trading, ccxt

I try to create a leverage trading bot with phemex API in python. I connected like this:

```
exchange = ccxt.phemex({
    'apiKey': API_KEY,
    'secret': API_SECRET,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'verbose': True
})
```

Then I got my actual Leverage on phemex with this snippet and also how much free BTC I do have to trade with.

```
params={"type":"swap","code":"BTC"}
response = exchange.fetch_balance(params=params)

#leverage = response['info']['data']['positions']['leverage']
positions = response['info']['data']['positions']
res = next((sub for sub in positions if sub['leverage']), None)
leverage = res['leverage']
free_BTC = response['BTC']['free']
used_BTC = response['BTC']['used']
```

Till here everything worked for me. Now I found a Code snippet for changing the leverage:

```
exchange.load_markets()

symbol = 'BTC/USD'
market = exchange.market(symbol)
exchange.verbose = Trueparams = {
    'symbol': market['id'],
    'leverage': 10
}
response = ex.privatePutPositionsLeverage(params)
pprint(response)
```

But the Leverage stillt stays at the old value.
Can someone help me with this issue. Thank you so much.

---

PS: These are the available funtions:

```
{'loadMarkets': True, 'cancelAllOrders': True, 'cancelOrder': True, 'cancelOrders': False, 'CORS': False, 'createDepositAddress': False, 'createLimitOrder': True, 'createMarketOrder': True, 'createOrder': True, 'deposit': False, 'editOrder': 'emulated', 'fetchBalance': True, 'fetchClosedOrders': True, 'fetchCurrencies': True, 'fetchDepositAddress': True, 'fetchDeposits': True, 'fetchL2OrderBook': True, 'fetchLedger': False, 'fetchMarkets': True, 'fetchMyTrades': True, 'fetchOHLCV': True, 'fetchOpenOrders': True, 'fetchOrder': True, 'fetchOrderBook': True, 'fetchOrderBooks': False, 'fetchOrders': True, 'fetchOrderTrades': False, 'fetchStatus': 'emulated', 'fetchTicker': True, 'fetchTickers': False, 'fetchTime': False, 'fetchTrades': True, 'fetchTradingFee': False, 'fetchTradingFees': False, 'fetchFundingFee': False, 'fetchFundingFees': False, 'fetchTradingLimits': False, 'fetchTransactions': False, 'fetchWithdrawals': True, 'privateAPI': True, 'publicAPI': True, 'signIn': False, 'withdraw': False}
```

Best regards
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function:

```
apiKeys = {}
phemex = ccxt.phemex(apiKeys)
phemex.set_leverage(10, 'BTC/USD:USD')
```

and finally you can get your position info with this function:

```
phemex.fetch_positions()
```

let me know if this doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for answering but it does not work. Phemex does not have the function set_leverage(). This is the result: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e0ae46d928a1> in <module>
----> 1 exchange.set_leverage(10, 'BTC/USD:USD')

AttributeError: 'phemex' object has no attribute 'set_leverage'` I can add the available functions in the question above.

Comment: @Dani make sure you are using the latest version of ccxt

Comment: you are amazing. Thank you so much, that was the mistake

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to update your CCXT version:

```
pip install ccxt --upgrade
```

This worked like a charm:

```
phemex.set_leverage(10, 'BTC/USD:USD')
```